# Optimize performance on large dataset

Tags: angular, ag-grid

We are using *[ag-Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/)* to display data. Now we would like to display around 30.000 rows with the free version.

My first try couldn´t handle this. The page was loading like forever.

The question is:
Is it even possible to display around 30.000 rows with *[ag-Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/)* without using the enterprise version and without using infinite scrolling?

Comment: Use a "next" and "prev" arrow solve that, but is what you want?

Comment: Would be an option, but can ag-grid handle it without having a paging on backend site? I mean, how is this example made with 100.000 datasets? https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php#/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that by enabling pagination ag-grid can easily handle this amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

What costs CPU ressources in this case is DOM manipulations, having 30000 * (Components per row) DOM objects will kill any browser, I don't think that any library could make any change to this.

A possible solution [is to use inifite scrolling](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-infinite-scrolling/), you can implement a server side solution or a front solution. This way, the browser will not have to render rows that no user ever will scroll into, also unload unused DOM objects to free some memory.